# How to remove single quotes with double quotes in java

Tags: java, regex, string, batch-file

I don't have any idea about regex pattern matching, and I am having a problem with single quotes in file path when when I run batch file through exec() command, I get the following error i.e

**Error is-**

**Windows cannot find 'C:\Program'.**

I am having trouble with single quotes when CMD tries to get into the desired directory.
So, anyone could tell me what to do here??

I created a batch file to compile and run java programs I have a function called createrunbat(String,String), and following code:

```
private File createrunbat(String str,String par)
 {
 if(str.startsWith("Text Editor-",0))
 {
     str=str.replaceFirst("Text Editor-","");
 }
 String sng,s2;
 File fe;
 try{

 FileOutputStream fos;
 DataOutputStream dos;

 sng=str;

 int a=sng.indexOf(".");

 sng=sng.substring(0,a);

 file=new File(jfc.getSelectedFile().getParent(),sng+".bat");

 fd=file.getAbsoluteFile();

 str=fd.getParent().substring(0, 2);

 fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
 dos=new DataOutputStream(fos);

 dos.writeBytes("@echo off \n");
 dos.writeBytes("cd\\"+"\n");

 if(fd.getParentFile().isDirectory())
 {
     dos.writeBytes(str+"\n");
 }
 s2=jfc.getSelectedFile().getParent();//I am having single quote problem from here
 dos.writeBytes("cd "+s2+"\\"+"\n");
 dos.writeBytes("javac "+sng+".java"+"\n");
 dos.writeBytes("java "+sng+" "+par+"\n");
 dos.writeBytes("pause \n");
 dos.writeBytes("exit \n");
 dos.close();
 }
 catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
 {
 }
 catch(IOException ex2)
 {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex2.toString());
 }

  return fd;
 }
```

Comment: Please also add the string sample which is giving you trouble.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with single quotes. The problem seems to be the blank in the file name `C:\Program Files\...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are perhaps confusing the error output with the input.

```
Windows cannot find 'C:\Program'.
```

The single quotes there are used to wrap the problematic data so you the developer know the boundaries of the input causing issues. The single quotes are not part of what your program interprets.

As others have suggested I imagine the real issue is the whitespace in your path. Your command line is reading the path as two separate arguments instead of one. Ironically, wrapping the path in quotes should fix the issue.

```
'C:\Program Files\SomePlace\...'
           ^ gets cut on whitespace and becomes two arguments instead of one:
'C:\Program' and 'Files\SomePlace\...'

'"C:\Program Files\SomePlace\..."'
 ^ quotes will keep the path together as a single argument
```

**Edit: How to wrap the path.**

Java1 has a good solution in their answer so I'll offer an alternative one that uses String formatting.

```
String safePath = String.format("\"%s\"", jfc.getSelectedFile().getParent().getAbsolutePath());
```

In this instance, the first argument to the String.format() method is the pattern to use, the second is the variable to substitute.
The actual quotes that will be around the path must be escaped (`\"`) as they have a special meaning in java to denote the start or end of a String. You must escape them to use them inside a String. The place-holder is where your path will be placed (`%s`).

**Side note:**

You should really use much more descriptive variable names in your code. It is quite bad practice to use names like `s2`, `sng`, `fe`, `fd`  and so on. Be descriptive and exact with your naming and following, debugging and writing your code will become easier.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but how do i put double quotes when the jfc.getSelectedFile().getParent() returns the string.

Comment: You can modify the returned string however you wish before you try to use it. Java1's answer above is one possibility. String formatting could also achieve the same result. `String safePath = String.format("\"%s\"", jfc.getSelectedFile().getParent().getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: i have one other question : would Runtime.getRuntime().exec(File) would be a good option here! thnks for edit

Comment: That would be a different matter entirely; you should make a new question to ask that. There's a one question per question rule around here. Also, if you've fixed your problem satisfactorily, please accept one of the answers so people with a similar issue know how to sort it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a rather more of a case that the blank in the path name is causing trouble and you will need to wrap quotes around the path

```
dos.writeBytes ("cd \"" + s2 +"\""+"\n");
```

Comment: I am still having the same problem with single quotes :

Comment: You question needs more information.  What single quotes?  Where they coming from?

Comment: The OP is perhaps confusing the error output with his input `Windows cannot find 'C:\Program'.` The single quotes there are used to wrap the problematic data so you the developer know the boundaries of the input causing issues. The single quotes are not part of what your program interprets.